# Difference-in-differences approach validity when binary outcome is 0 during pre-treatment period & always 0 for control units

Tags: causality, binary-data, difference-in-difference

In the context of evaluating the effectiveness of some intervention on a binary outcome, using a difference-in-differences design, if the outcome is 0 for all study units during the pre-treatment period (e.g. the outcome cannot happen until the intervention occurs), and remains zero for all control units during the post-treatment period, but at least some intervention units are 1s in the post-treatment period, does it still make sense statistically to evaluate this using the standard difference-in-differences OLS estimator or an equivalent logistic regression?

More generally for impact/effectiveness evaluation does it even make sense to use any kind of controlled pre-post comparison (like DiD, an RCT, an interrupted time series etc) for an outcome that is guaranteed to be 0 for intervention and control units during the pre-treatment period and for control units during the post-treatment period? Or should you just look at the pre-post change in the intervention group given the control is guaranteed to be 0?

I can't find any literature providing advice or examples for such a scenario. Any advice, particularly published references, would be gratefully received.

Comment: The idea of diff-in-diff is that there can be a difference from pre- to post-treatment period in the treatment and in the control group. If there can't be a difference in one of them, I don't see a need to do diff-in-diff, although it probably wouldn't be wrong, just more complex than necessary.

Comment: Yes agreed. I am mainly interested in finding some relevant literature/examples backing up this seemingly logical view, as I am concerned about how it would be viewed at peer review if publishing results from a study following this approach.